# Searching english word list storing in a db

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am going to build a project in which i need the English words. I need all the words for my app. For this i need to have a sq l lite db which i can use for my project. I have searched a lot for a database which contains the English words. But can't find any solution. Let me clear my problem. I need a sq l lite database for my android project which can i connect to my android app make query.This db will contain all the word starting with 'a%' to 'z%'.

Comment: What's the question? Can't you just store words from a word list in the DB? (That's a fairly large DB, btw, although it depends on what you mean by "all".)

Comment: yes it is going to be a large db. And i am not able to find the efficeint way to import data in the db.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to google for a scrabble word list. They'll contain basically everything you need, and you can find them in Excel formats, along with .csv for easy import into a database.

The more popular ones are called TWL and SOWPODS, so a search for those in particular will get you what you need.

Comment: I can't find any wordlist db in that particular site :(

Comment: What particular site? Google?

Comment: twl or sowpods... it will be really helpful if you give the link of the sql lite db file .

Answer (score 0):

Google for for dictionary database in excel or any other db format and then import it.

Answer (score 0):

try using the files from the firefox dictionary.
Somewhere hesitate downloading a file with all the words separated by `<ENTER>` (#13)

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/language-tools/